# After scheduling a BigQuery task using standard SQL, is there a way to send the CSV file to a list of mail recipients?

Tags: sql, firebase, google-analytics, google-bigquery, scheduled-tasks

Need to run a scheduled task on BigQuery, using incremental date. Since data  is displayed correctly for only T-2 days. Is there a way to format a date for 2 days prior and run the scheduled task such that the result is exported in CSV format and sent to list of mail recipients?

I can only see an option for table append or table create. This is not of much help as I need the results to be exported in CSV file and sent to a group of users on gmail.

```
_TABLE_SUFFIX = "20190920"
```

Comment: Check [Magnus](https://potensio.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/categories/115000401632-Magnus) part of [Potens.io](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/potens-io/potensio) suite of  powerful and efficient  tools for BigQuery designed so that even the non-engineer can easily explore and automate workflows to become self-sufficient in their data needs like in your question. Disclosure: Google Developer Expert in Cloud here - author of BigQuery Mate and Potens.io (Magnus and Goliath) productivity tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/) to schedule actions

as it only supports triggering:

- Pub/Sub
- App Engine HTTP
- HTTP

You need to script the rest of the process, but it might be a small piece of code to trigger the CSV export and to email.  You will do this in a Google Cloud Function that can be hit by HTTP, or build a [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/) container to run your containerized app (well your small scripts).

Answer (score 0):

You can use composer(Airflow) and schedule invocation of DAG.
Inside the DAG you will create a job which will call a python script using PythonOperator.
This script will fetch data from bigquery then dump data in one destination table. You will read from this table and save results in csv format on GCS. Once this is done, you will
create a SendMail task which will send out the emails.